# Updating ObservableCollection from non UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, windows-store-apps

I am working on a Windows 8 Store app. I have a timer that calls a delegate every two minutes and makes an async web request. The resulting data is added to an observablecollection that is bound to a UI element. Doing this throws an exception because the UI is being modified on a non UI thread.
In other places in my code I have done this

```
await Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync( CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
    ui code here
}
```

But this is causing a crash with Window.Current being null. I tried passing Window.Current into the delegate as a parameter but this throws a different exception. Are there any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually easier to have the UI thread call background operations rather than having the background operations update the UI thread.

So, I recommend you use [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer), and then you won't need to use `Dispatcher` at all.

Comment: if it is code that is run logically/once when called, i.e not needing a timer that schedules.. is there a simpler way to avoid dispatcher and the window.current == null problem?

Comment: @Allstar: I'm not clear on the requirements. Could you post your own question along with code?

Comment: @StephenCleary , here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522322/correct-way-to-access-ui-from-background-thread-in-uwp   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
```

or

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
```